# Vue - Export Rendered HTML from v-html component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, electron, vuejs3

I am using `sheetjs` to generate some HTML from an Excel range, using the `sheet_to_html()` function. I then use that HTML to render a table using `v-html`. The user can then perform some actions to the table that adds/removes classes. I am trying to save the out rendered HTML as a string after the user modified classes.

My Vue component:

```
<script setup>
import { utils } from 'xlsx';

const htmlParse = utils.sheet_to_html(worksheet)

function classModifier(event){
    const clickedElement = event.target
    clickedElement.classList.toggle("my-class")
}

</script>

<template>
   <div @click="classModifier" v-html="htmlParse"></div>
</template>
```

After the user clicks around the table modify the classes, I would like to get the updated HTML with new classes. I'm using Vue.js within Electron.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a [template ref](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/template-refs.html) for this:

```js
<script setup>
import { utils } from 'xlsx';

const htmlParse = utils.sheet_to_html(worksheet)

function classModifier(event){
    const clickedElement = event.target
    clickedElement.classList.toggle("my-class")
}

const div = ref(null);

// later on in some kind of save callback or whatever
div.value.innerHTML

</script>

<template>
   <div @click="classModifier" v-html="htmlParse" ref="div"></div>
</template>
```

Comment: So if I use the `div.value.innerHTML` elsewhere in a function that, for example, exported the HTML - it would capture whatever the current HTML is within the div?

Comment: yeah (obligatory extra words to satisfy minimum length)